# Почему вместо \\x не появляется \x

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я хочу заменить у тензора символ \\x на \x

```
import tensorflow as tf


rank_1_tensor = tf.constant([b"{{g|attr('\\x5f\\x5fclass\\x5f\\x5f')}}"])
stripped=tf.strings.regex_replace(rank_1_tensor, b'\\\\x', b'\\x')
```

Но в итоге stripped оказывается равен - `b"{{g|attr('5f5fclass5f5f')}}"`
А мне нужно, чтобы stripped был равен `b"{{g|attr('\x5f\x5fclass\x5f\x5f')}}"`

Как верно реализовать такое?

### UPD Пример исходной байтовой строки

Она получается путём чтения функцией text_dataset_from_directory, затем вывожу на экран получившееся

```
raw_train_ds = preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    shuffle=0, # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    seed=seed)

for text_batch, label_batch in raw_train_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(batch_size):#10):
    print("Packet: ", text_batch.numpy()[i][:100], '...')
    print("Label:", label_batch.numpy()[i])
```

но почему-то данные два раза экранируются, пример вывода

```
Packet:  b"{{g['__class__']['__mro__'][1]['__subclasses__']()[428]('antthing.txt', 'w').write('Hello here !')}}" ...
Label: 0
Packet:  b"{{g['\\x5f\\x5fclass\\x5f\\x5f']['\\x5f\\x5fbase\\x5f\\x5f']}}"
```

Не решив эту пробему, думал решить её нормализацией, путем замены двойного слэша на одиночный (чтобы превратился в байт), но и это не сработало (описал в начале вопроса)

Comment: Приведите пример исходной байтовой строки из rank_1_tensor, которую вы пытаетесь изменить.

Comment: @insolor, добавил пример

Comment: Какая-то обфускация в `Packet:  b"{{g['__class__']['__mro__'][1]['__subclasses__']()[428]('antthing.txt', 'w').write('Hello here !')}}" ...`...

Comment: @gil9red , это различные payload'ы , нашел тут - https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/Server%20Side%20Template%20Injection#jinja2

Comment: Пробовали без регекса такую замену? `replace(rank_1_tensor, b'\\x5f', b'\x5f')`

Comment: @insolor, в определении для тензора строк нет такого метода( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/regex_replace

Comment: Так как строка является сложной цепочкой шестнадцатеричных цифр и слов, то предлагают её декодировать. В TensorFlow есть функции для этого, например - tf.strings.unicode_decode_with_offsets. Вот обсуждение вашей проблемы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50199840/python3-replacing-double-backslash-with-single-backslash